# ListView item height is always same (and wrong)

Tags: android, listview

I'm trying to resize `ListView` to show all items.

```
final ListAdapter adapter = timeline.getAdapter();
int totalHeight = 0;
final int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(timeline.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
    final View listItem = adapter.getView(i, null, timeline);
    listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    Log.v(TAG, "Item size = " + listItem.getMeasuredHeight());  // Always 38
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
final ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = timeline.getLayoutParams();
params.height = totalHeight;
timeline.setLayoutParams(params);
timeline.requestLayout();
```

Why is `listItem.getMeasuredHeight()` always 38, disregard `android:layout_height` specified in item's XML layout.

The `getView()` method is pretty standard:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;

    if (view == null) {
        final LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.timeline_item, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    final ActivityLogItem log = (ActivityLogItem) getItem(position);
    holder.time.setText(format.print(log.getRecordedTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault())));
    holder.time.setTextColor(log.isImportant() ? view.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange) : Color.WHITE);
    holder.event.setText(log.getLocalizedType(view.getResources()));
    holder.event.setTextColor(log.isImportant() ? view.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange) : Color.BLACK);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: if you trying to make listview height exactly the same of its total item height, then you would miss the core usage of adapter

Comment: item height is not wrong. It's just not what you want it to be.